# Drupal 7 tabs and links

Tags: tabs, drupal-7, account

I saw an website for [example](https://www.lapensiuni.ro/cazare-transilvania/brasov/Pensiunea-Milenium-Residence-5050058/index.html) . And I wonder if it's possible to do same user account like in that website.  Especially tabs with different links in user account.
Unfortunately I'm new in Drupal and I don't know how to start. I'm sorry for my English. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Field group module**](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) for creating tabs and grouping the fields.

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group

Answer (score 0):

You can use views Modules to get these types of views

see this video, May be this helpful-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoSnUO9KB00